# PHP page: implement Multiple choice and True/False (Quiz)

Tags: php, html, css

This webpage fetches Questions and answers stored in two different tables called questions and answers. I am able to successfully fetch the data from the database and represent it. The problem is the evaluation part. As the number of questions are unknown so how I am supposed to change the value of label dynamically? Also while implementing it for a single question (ie: only one question in the database) I am not able to get the correct result. Can Anyone please help me?

My Code :-

```
<?php

include("session.php");
include("exam_session.php");
echo "Hello ".$username;
echo " Click Here To Log Out... <a href='logout.php'> LogOut!</a>";
echo "<br /><br /> Quiz Code : ".$code;
?>
<?php
//$variable_name=array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight');
$qu=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions where code='".$code."'");
//$la=mysql_fetch_array($qu);
//echo "No of Questions : ".$la;
//$limit=$_SESSION['maid'];

if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    $last=0;
    $marks=0;
    $te=$_POST['one'].$_POST['one'];
    echo "<br> Value : ".$_POST['one'];
    if( isset($_POST['one']) ) {
        echo "You have selected :".$_POST['one'];
        //echo "<br />ONE : ".$PayPlatform;
        //if($PayPlatfrom=='A')
        $marks+=1;
    }
    $last+=1;
    $_SESSION["marks"] = $marks;
    echo $_SESSION['marks'];
    echo "<br />Marks : ".$marks;
    $_SESSION["tot_ques"] = $qu;
    header("location: last_ans.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$variable_name=array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight');
//print_r($variable_name);
$macount=0;
//$temp=$variable_name[$macount];
//echo "<br /> Temp : ".$temp;
$maid=0;
$matf=0;
$zids=0;
$query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions");
$query5=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$rows=$row[0];  
$row5=mysql_fetch_array($query5);
$rows5=$row5[0];    
$query1=mysql_query("select question_id,question,type,code from questions");
$query6=mysql_query("select id,question_id,answer,correct from answers");

for($i=0; $i<$rows ; $i++) {
    $ans=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
    $name=$ans['code'];
    if($name == $code) {
        $msg=$ans['question'];
        echo '<div id="msg_pst"><br />
        Question : <br /><br /><p class="msps"> '.$msg.' </p><br /><br />
        </div>';
        $types=$ans['type'];
        $quest1=$ans['question_id'];
        for($k=0;$k<$rows5;$k++) {
            //echo "inside k ";
            $ans5=mysql_fetch_array($query6);
            $quest2=$ans5['question_id'];
            if($quest1==$quest2) {
                //echo "inside j";
                if($types=="mc") {
                    $temp=$variable_name[$maid];
                    echo "Temp : ".$temp;
                    $msg5=$ans5['answer'];
                    $correct=$ans5['correct'];
                    if($correct==1) {
                        //$divid=$variable_name($zids);
                        echo '<div id="msg_pst">
                        <input type="radio" name="one" value= A /> '.$msg5.'
                        </div>';
                        $macount+=1;
                        if($macount%4==0) {
                            $maid+=1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if($correct!=1) {
                        echo ' <div id="msg_pst">
                        <input type=radio name="one" value=False /> '.$msg5.'
                        </div>';
                        $macount+=1;
                        if($macount%4==0) {
                            $maid+=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if($types=="tf") {
                    $msg5=$ans5['question_id'];
                    $correct=$ans5['correct'];
                    if($correct==1) {
                        echo '<div id="msg_pst">
                        <input type=radio name='.$maid.' id='.$maid.' value=A /> <p class="msps"> '.$msg5.' </p>
                        </div>';                                    
                        $matf+=1;
                        if($matf%2==0) {
                            $maid+=1;
                            $matf=0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if($correct!=1) {
                        echo '<div id="msg_pst">
                        <input type=radio name='.$maid.' id='.$maid.' value=False /> <p class="msps"> '.$msg5.' </p>
                        </div>';
                        $matf+=1;
                        if($matf%2==0) {
                            $maid+=1;
                            $matf=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
//echo "<br / Maid : >".$maid;
//session_start();
$_SESSION['maid']=$maid;
?>
<form action="exam.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key thing you need to make your code work is a while loop. In your case a while loop is useful because it loops through the same bit of code for every row in your database, even though you don't know how many rows there are.

Your code:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Should be:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    //This is one row in your database
    //It will run code inside here to every row in your table
    //You could do something like echo "<label>{$row['question_name']}</label>"; to dynamically create labels. 
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Hopefully this is the bit you are looking for.

Comment: "While loops are used when you don't now how many of an item you will have" - not always true. While loops are used for much more. Consider rephrasing this to say that in OP's case a while loop such as that will loop through each result until there are none left.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The textbook answer is to use while loops when you don't know how many times you need to iterate, but I definitely agree that while loops can be used for a whole lot more. Hopefully my edit helps clarify that.